# ValueError: expected an element of either Enum('solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', 'dotdash', 'dashdot')

Tags: bokeh

I'm attempting to output a line graph with the dash being driven by the data.  My example is:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]
z = ['dashed', 'dashed', 'dashed', 'solid', 'solid']

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.line(x, y, line_width=2, line_dash=z)

show(p)
```

However, this results in:

> ValueError: expected an element of either Enum('solid', 'dashed', 'dotted', 'dotdash', 'dashdot'), Regex('^(\d+(\s+\d+)*)?$') or Seq(Int), got ['dashed', 'dashed', 'dashed', 'solid', 'solid']

Is it possible to set the line type based on my dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set the line dash using a list for the line glyph.

A few things that could help you resolve your issue. Try using the `MultiLine` glyph for the plot and the `ColumnDataSource` to structure your data. Using the `MultiLine` glyph it is possible to set some line properties to change for each segment of the multi line. `line_color` can be changed for each segment that way, but unfortunately the `line_dash` property cannot.

You could try opening an issue on [Bokeh's Github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) to allow the `line_dash` property in the `MultiLine` glyph to be set from a `ColumnDataSource`.

Here's an exemple of what a solution could look like.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiLine

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(z=['dashed', 'dashed', 'solid', 'solid'],
                                    xs=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]],
                                    ys=[[6, 7], [7, 2], [2, 4], [4, 5]],
                                    color=['green', 'red', 'green', 'green']))

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

glyph = MultiLine(xs='xs', ys='ys', line_color = 'color', line_dash='z', line_width=2)
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)

show(p)
```

In the above code, the color can be set using the `ColumnDataSource` this can be used to distinguish the segments, but the `line_dash` property will still produce the error.